# Nvidia-prime and gdm dont work on ubuntu-gnome

Tags: nvidia, gnome, graphics, gdm, hybrid-graphics

I have managed to install the correct drivers for my Nvidia Geforce 940MX on my asus i5 laptop. When I open NVIDIA X Server Settings, I have the option to choose between my two GPUs (NVIDIA (Performance Mode); Intel (Power Saving Mode)) but when I change from intel to Nvidia and vice versa. It asks me to log out to apply the changes. When I log out and back in again, I get a blank screen for a second, and then am returned to the gnome login screen, every time I try to log in. I have tried reinstalling the drivers and flushing all Nvidia software but this has had no effect. When I reboot, however, the GPU changes. So this leads me to believe that the problem lies with gdm3 and gnome-shell.

I am running ubuntu gnome 17.04 with:

- GNOME Shell 3.24.2
- GDM 3.24.1
- Nvidia binary driver - version 375.66 from nvidia-375
- Processor microcode firmware for intel cpus from intel-microcode

I have tried "service gdm restart" from a non-gui tty and this makes no difference.

Any help will be appreciated especially considering Ubuntu's move away from unity to gnome shell ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related with this bug in [GDM](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747339).

Anyway, the best workaround in Ubuntu GNOME is to change GDM to lightdm (in fact, lightdm in Ubuntu is way better than gdm, imho):

1. Install lightdm

   `sudo apt install lightdm`
2. Switch the DE to lightdm

   `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`
3. Reboot

   `sudo reboot`